# Изменение данных одного ViewColtroller'а из другого

Tags: objective-c

Добрый вечер! Понимаю, что тема достаточно затерта,но почитав и покопавшись рабочего результата так и не нашел, а может просто чего-то не допонимаю. Итак, есть Tab Bar Controller, с двумя вкладками, на одной из них кнопка и Progress View а на другой просто Progress View, подскажите как реализовать, что бы по нажатию кнопки прогресс изменялся и на той вкладке где нет кнопки. Стоит ли копать в сторону NSNotificationCenter, или же есть решение проще?

Comment: Куда уж проще NSNotificationCenter?

Comment: Вопрос решен, и впрямь очень удобный механизм!